I want to move and rotate the group using gsap instead of framer motion
function Dice({ node, mouse, multiplier }) {
  const {position, rotation, scale} = node;
    const rotationX = useTransform(mouse.x, [0, 1], [rotation.x - multiplier, rotation.x + multiplier]);
    const rotationY = useTransform(mouse.y, [0, 1], [rotation.y - multiplier, rotation.y + multiplier]);
    const positionX = useTransform(mouse.x, [0, 1], [position.x - multiplier, position.x + multiplier]);
    const positionY = useTransform(mouse.y, [0, 1], [position.y + multiplier, position.y - multiplier]);
    return(
        <motion.group
        position={position}
        rotation={rotation}
        scale={scale}
        rotation-x={rotationY}
        rotation-y={rotationX}
        position-x={positionX}
        position-y={positionY}
        >
            <mesh
                castShadow={node.children[0].castShadow}
                receiveShadow={node.children[0].receiveShadow}
                geometry={node.children[0].geometry}
                material={node.children[0].material}
            />
            <mesh
                castShadow={node.children[1].castShadow}
                receiveShadow={node.children[1].receiveShadow}
                geometry={node.children[1].geometry}
                material={node.children[1].material}
            />
        </motion.group>
    )
}

so I wrote this function that make the dice 3d model on my website follow the cursor, but I noticed that that perfomance is bad and the website is a bit laggy, and that's why I would like to know how I can make the same result using gsap instead of framer motion to move that group since gsap is more optimized and performs better.
